# v14 Layout File is not updating

Tags: android, android-layout

I have developed an android app with minSdk = 10 now I want to add a *Switch* in one of the Activity (has the layout file with name content_main.xml).

As the Switch need the minSdk to be 14, I have updated the same in AndroidManifest and

```
<uses-sdk
    android:minSdkVersion="14"
    android:targetSdkVersion="20" />
```

But when I added the Switch on the xml, it still giving an error as the

> View requires API level 14 (current min is 10)

Moreover Android Studio automatically created a duplicate layout file, one for the current sdk version and another for API level 14 and they are not being updated automatically, which creates a conflict in the UI.

Please do let me know, how to safely merge these two layout files to one to avoid the conflict. As I need a switch, how will use in this case (as the application does not seem to respond to Manifest file)

Comment: try to delete auto generated v14 layout file, put minsdkversion= 14 and clean and rebuild the project.

Comment: Tried to delete the v14 file, but the AndroidStudio deleted the other one as well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If using android Studio, you should look at your build.gradle and check minSdkVersion !

Comment: and don't forget to clean then rebuild project - fixes many issues. If this answer works for you, please marks this as the solution.